# Why can this map reduce program use an unqualified `Context` without import it?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am studying a Hadoop MapReduce example from https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0

Does `Context`in the program refer to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.Context.html?

If yes, why can it uses unqualified `Context` without `import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context`?

Thanks.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
public class WordCount {
  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }
  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how the full class name of `Context` is

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context
```

`Context` is an inner class in `Mapper`. Because the `WordCount` class extends `Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>` and that `Mapper` class contains the inner class `Context`, the class WordCount has direct access to the `Context` class without importing it.  It already imports `Mapper` **and** extends it.  Usually just importing it is not enough to give you access to the inner class, but the difference maker here is extending `Mapper`.

Comment: Thanks. Why is `Context` not accessed by `Mapper.Context`, but by `Context`?

Comment: Because WordCount is a subclass of Mapper, it has direct access to the inner class, no need to qualify it.